# After Installing Artifactory with Helm, pods having issues

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod, helm3

doing some projects to learn kubernetes

I have an **EKS** (aws) Cluster, using **helm** to install **Artifactory**. Installation goes well I go to access Artifactory through Load Balancer URL and its not working. I check the **pods** and..

```bash
$ kubectl get pods -n tools
NAME                                             READY   STATUS     RESTARTS       AGE
artifactory-0                                    0/1     Init:3/5   0              90m
artifactory-artifactory-nginx-7c4dcfdbbc-xn4wk   0/1     Running    11 (98s ago)   89m
artifactory-postgresql-0                         1/1     Running    0              3h32m
jenkins-0                                        2/2     Running    0              3h34m
```

Tried to troubleshoot it

```
$ kubectl logs artifactory-0 -n tools
Defaulted container "artifactory" out of: artifactory, delete-db-properties (init), remove-lost-found (init), copy-system-yaml (init), wait-for-db (init), migration-artifactory (init)
Error from server (BadRequest): container "artifactory" in pod "artifactory-0" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

```
$ kubectl logs artifactory-artifactory-nginx-7c4dcfdbbc-xn4wk -n tools
Defaulted container "nginx" out of: nginx, setup (init)
```

Used kubectl describe on **artifactory-artifactory-nginx-7c4dcfdbbc-xn4wk**

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  110s (x1235 over 111m)  kubelet  Startup probe failed:
```

**artifactory-0** had no events

Comment: the event says the startup probe failed. [I would start here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/). If you post the deployment yaml that would also help

Comment: I used https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/jfrog/artifactory/107.41.6, helm upgrade --install artifactory jfrog/artifactory